# How can I fix this "IndentationError: expected an indented block"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, nlp, topic-modeling

```
def remove_stopwords(text,nlp,custom_stop_words=None,remove_small_tokens=True,min_len=2):
    if custom_stop_words:
       nlp.Defaults.stop_words |= custom_stop_words
    filtered_sentence =[] 
    doc = nlp (text)
    for token in doc:
    
        if token.is_stop == False: 
        
           if remove_small_tokens:
              if len(token.text)>min_len:
                 filtered_sentence.append(token.text)
          else:
              filtered_sentence.append(token.text) 
              return " ".join(filtered_sentence) 
          if len(filtered_sentence)>0
          else None
```

I am getting the error for the last else:

The goal of this last part is, if after the stopword removal, words are still left in the sentence, then the sentence should be returned as a string else return null. I'd be so thankful for any advice.

```
else None
^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Comment: Please fix the formatting.

Comment: `if len(filtered_sentence)>0: else None` is incorrect python syntax

Comment: Thank you! I removed the ":" from the end, but it seems like this wasn't the problem... Do you have an idea how I can write it correct?

Comment: Just move `return " ".join(filtered_sentence) if len(filtered_sentence)>0 else None` to the same line

Comment: Thank you for your help! This was a great advice and in addition I had to correct the indention in the entire piece of code

Comment: There are many things wrong in this code. I **strongly** recommend following a proper Python tutorial from start to finish, before trying to use advanced third-party libraries. The fundamentals are essential.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your entire code is not properly indented

```py
def remove_stopwords(text,nlp,custom_stop_words=None,remove_small_tokens=True,min_len=2):
    if custom_stop_words:
        nlp.Defaults.stop_words |= custom_stop_words

    filtered_sentence =[] 
    doc = nlp (text)
    for token in doc:
        
        if token.is_stop == False: 
            
            if remove_small_tokens:
                if len(token.text)>min_len:
                    filtered_sentence.append(token.text)
            else:
                filtered_sentence.append(token.text)
                
    if len(filtered_sentence) > 0:           
        return " ".join(filtered_sentence) 
    else:
        return None
```

Comment: Thank you a thousand times! This was the decisive hint to make it work properly. I can't tell you how happy I am that this finally works, thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to use the [ternary operator](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/ternary_operators.html).

The format for it is `x if condition else y` this is on the same line and without the `:` after the if else.

So your last return statement should be :

```py
return " ".join(filtered_sentence) if len(filtered_sentence)>0 else None
```